# How to add broadleaf site homepage banner slider with different offer banner with same priority?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, broadleaf-commerce

I have created different offer ads in Broadleaf database. I want to make this as slide on site home page. Please help me to put html slider on the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have defined the ads in the admin console, than you can pull them from BL with the blc:content tag into the templates

this is how i create a caroussel banner, that rotates several images on our landing page

```
   <ul id="slider">
        <blc:content contentType="Carousel Banner"/>
        <li th:each="item : ${contentList}">
            <a th:href="'/shop/' + ${item['targetUrl']}">
                <img th:src="'/shop/' + ${item['imageUrl']}"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

the result looks similar to this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XFcSv/

here you can find instructions about blc:content and how to use it:

http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/admin-usage-tutorials/using-structured-content